# Access value enumeration field fom content part in Editor Method Orchard

Tags: field, orchardcms, enumeration, orchardcms-1.8

I want to access the selectedvalue (enumeration field) in content part when click submit save button in widget administrator. How I can do that in Editor Method?

Comment: Where do you want to have that value? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want this: click save button when creating a custom widget. In Editor Method get de selectedvalue from Enumeration Field Attached in Migrations file. Depending the selectedvalue i want do stuff, but i need to know how to get that value (Fields.EnumerationsFields.SelectedValue).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the ContentPart that has that field, you can do it like this:

`(dynamic)contentItem.ContentPartName.FieldName.SelectedValue`

But if you don't know the name of the ContentPart, you can first use this to get all the fields of the content item at runtime:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;

// get all the fields from the contentItem without knowing part name

var callSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>
    .Create(Binder.GetMember(0, contentItem.ContentType,
    ((dynamic)contentItem).GetType(), new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(0, null) }));

var contentItemFields = ((callSite.Target(callSite, ((dynamic)contentItem))).Fields) as List<ContentField>;
```

Having the list of fields, you now can search for the EnumerationField that you want, and get the selected value:

```
var yourField = (contentItemFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.name == "YourField")) as EnumerationField;
var selectedValue = yourField.SelectedValue;
```